# Sql server isn't able to display records on LAN through asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am running ASP.NET application on the intranet.
I am using SQL Server 2008 to show records.
My system acts the main server. Firewall is off on all systems.

Now when my friend,on his computer, opens my asp.net site via my ip-address then all the pages are displayed properly. But the pages where the records are to be shown from the database, they experience problems. The problem is that the records are not being displayed. No exception occurs. 
I am using windows authentication on my SQL Server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on that info... we have no idea. You need to add some logging and ensure you are not catching an exception without handling/displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is difficult to know without a bit more information, this smells like a case of SQL Server permission problems.  Does your friend have a SQL Server (not Windows) login on your database server (and has that login been mapped in SSMS to the database in question)?  If so, have you tried logging in with his ID on your computer to see if that generates different behavior?